# Next Js Loop through object to map and remove duplicates for dropdown value for each select

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am trying to generate dropdown values from the below JSON but am unable to remove duplicate values from each dropdown.

```
  const [items] = useState([
  {
      "Id": 502,
      "CityId": 2,
      "CityName": "Ex. Mumbai",
      "DepartureId": 3762,
      "DeptDate": "22 Jul 2022 "
    },
    {
      "Id": 502,
      "CityId": 2,
      "CityName": "Ex. Mumbai",
      "DepartureId": 3763,
      "DeptDate": "05 Aug 2022 "
    },
    {
      "Id": 502,
      "CityId": 1,
      "CityName": "Ex. Ahmedabad",
      "DepartureId": 3762,
      "DeptDate": "22 Jul 2022 "
    },
    {
      "Id": 502,
      "CityId": 7,
      "CityName": "Ex. Delhi",
      "DepartureId": 3762,
      "DeptDate": "22 Jul 2022 "
    },
    {
      "Id": 502,
      "CityId": 9,
      "CityName": "Ex. Bangalore",
      "DepartureId": 3762,
      "DeptDate": "22 Jul 2022 "
    },
    {
      "Id": 502,
      "CityId": 9,
      "CityName": "Ex. Bangalore",
      "DepartureId": 3763,
      "DeptDate": "05 Aug 2022 "
    },
]);
```

My Dropdowns:

[CityName](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zudFq.png)   [DeptDate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQNY2.png)

using

```
<select>
            {items.map(item => (
                <option  key={item.CityId} value={item.CityId}>
                    {item.CityName}
                </option>
            ))}
</select>
```

Also, I tried using

```
{Array.from(new Set(items.map(obj => obj.CityName))).map(cn => {
                return <option value={cn.CityName}>{cn}</option>
            })}
```

but don't know how to add "cn.CityId" as an option value when looping using only "obj.CityName".

How can I fix this? Thank you for support in Advance !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove duplicate element in array by simple function

```
const cityNames = items.map(i => i.CityName);
const deptDates = items.map(i => i.DeptDate);
const filtereName = items.filter(({ CityName }, index) => !cityNames.includes(CityName , index + 1))
const filtereDate = items.filter(({ DeptDate}, index) => !deptDates.includes(DeptDate, index + 1))

<select>
    {filtereName.map(item => (
        <option  key={item.CityId} value={item.CityId}>
            {item.CityName}
        </option>
    ))}
</select>
```

Comment: Thank You @iamhuynq, this solved my problem and I also learnt to map & filters individually. Can you please help give insights to dynamically select value in second dropdown based on first dropdown?

Comment: @user3584810 yea sure, can you give more information

Comment: I figured it out, I will modify my json bit like each CityName, add sub object with all DeptDate associated with this CityName. Thank you for assistance !!

Comment: Hi @iamhuynq, Can you please help me how to achieve this result `[{"Id":502,"CityId":2,"CityName":"Ex. Mumbai","Dates":[{"DepartureId":3762,"DeptDate":"22 Jul 2022 "},{"DepartureId":3763,"DeptDate":"05 Aug 2022 "}]},{"Id":502,"CityId":1,"CityName":"Ex. Ahmedabad","Dates":[{"DepartureId":3762,"DeptDate":"22 Jul 2022 "}]}]` using filter and reduce functions from above json `const [items] = ` Here I am merging objects having same value.

Comment: const objectItems = items.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  if (!acc[cur.CityId])
    acc[cur.CityId] = {
      ...cur,
      Dates: [
        {
          DepartureId: cur.DepartureId,
          DeptDate: cur.DeptDate
        }
      ]
    };
  else {
    acc[cur.CityId].Dates.push({
      DepartureId: cur.DepartureId,
      DeptDate: cur.DeptDate
    });
  }
  return acc;
}, {});
const result = Object.values(objectItems);

Comment: @user3584810 can u check?

Comment: Thank You so much @iamhuynq, your support solved my query !!